# Using Iteration in Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, iteration

I am dealing with stocks (when to buy/sell and how many stocks to hold)

I am a begginer trying to move from small sample sizes in Excel to larger sample sizes in R.

I will try to explain my problem with a reproducible example. If it is not understandable let me know and I will try to clarify.

I have two stocks:

```
AAPL.price <- c(140,145,150,148,152,156,153)
MSFT.price <- c(70,75,73,74,73,76,74)
price <- data.frame (AAPL.price,MSFT.price)
```

And I also have a data frame that tells me when to buy and when to sell a given stock (1 is buy and -1 is sell)

```
AAPL <- c(1,-1,0,1,0,0,-1)
MSFT <- c(0,0,1,0,-1,0,1)
decision <- data.frame (AAPL,MSFT)
```

Moreover, I have also created a formula that tells me how many stocks I hold at each point in time. But, as the number of stocks depend for example of the cash available, I have created a function that would always tell me that when I buy a stock I always by 100 (just for simplicity hoping that I could change it later).

The function is:

```
numberstocks <- function(x) {

newValue <- 0

for (i in 1:length(x)) {

    if (x[i] == -1) {
        newValue <- -100
    } else if (x[i] == 1) {
        newValue <- 100
    } else if (x[i] == 0 && newValue != 100) {
        newValue <- 0
    }
    x[i] <- newValue
}

return(x)

}
```

And by applying `decision2 <- as.data.frame (lapply(decision,numberstocks))` I get a data frame with value 100 when I hold the stock and -100 when I sell it.

After this, I proceeded to the computation of cash. For this I added two columns to my data frame: one with my cash movements (from buying and selling) and one from my actual value in cash.

```
positivevalues <- function (x)
sapply (seq_along(x),function (i) {
    if (x[i] < -0.5) {
        100
    }else{
        x[i]
    }
})

decision3 <- as.data.frame (lapply(decision2[,1:2], positivevalues))
decision2$cashmov <- with (decision2, c(rowSums(decision*price*decision3)))

decision2$cash <- with (decision2, c(1000000, matrix(0,6,1)))
decision2$cash <- 0
    for (i in 1) {
    decision2$cash [i] = 1000000
    }
    for (i in 2:7){
    decision2$cash [i] = decision2$cash[i-1]-decision2$cashmov[i]
}
```

Finally, I have also created a column that tells me the number of stocks that I am buying at each period.

```
decision2$numberbuys <- with (decision2, c(rowSums(decision>0)))
```

What I would want is that for each point, when I buy the stock, instead of having "100", I would like to have

```
decision2$cash[i-1]/decision2$numberbuys[i]/price
```

Which would impact the cash at period [i] thus impacting the number of stocks in [i+1] and so on.

Could someone help me with this?

I am sorry if it is too confusing, I tried to be as clear as possible.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have a problem with next realization:
`decision2$cash[i-1]/decision2$numberbuys[i]/price`.

#### Input

```
con <- textConnection("AAPL MSFT    cash cashmov numberbuys
100    0 1000000   14000          1
-100    0 1014500  -14500          0
   0  100 1007200    7300          1
 100  100  992400   14800          1
 100 -100  999700   -7300          0
 100    0  999700       0          0
-100  100 1007600   -7900          1")

decision2 <- read.table(con, header = T)

df <- data.frame(cash = decision2$cash, numberbuys = decision2$numberbuys)

#cash.offset column is decision2$cash[i-1]
df$cash.offset <- c(NA, df$cash[1:nrow(df) - 1])
df$res <- df$cash.offset / df$numberbuys

df$AAPL <- df$res / decision2$AAPL
df$MSFT <- df$res / decision2$MSFT

df$AAPL[is.infinite(df$AAPL)] <- 0
df$MSFT[is.infinite(df$MSFT)] <- 0

print(df)
```

#### Output

```
     cash numberbuys cash.offset     res  AAPL  MSFT
1 1000000          1          NA      NA    NA    NA
2 1014500          0     1000000     Inf     0     0
3 1007200          1     1014500 1014500     0 10145
4  992400          1     1007200 1007200 10072 10072
5  999700          0      992400     Inf     0     0
6  999700          0      999700     Inf     0     0
7 1007600          1      999700  999700 -9997  9997
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but actually that is not my problem. My problem is how can I make the first and second columns of decision 2 (AAPL and MSFT) dependent on previous values of cash. I would like to divide the column "res" that you have created by the price of each stock. And then I would like to reevaluate the value of the same number of stocks at the point where I sell the stock which will then have an impact on cash. Am I making myself clear?

Comment: I've added columns with `res / price` for both stock symbols. I hope that you can reevaluate the values by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However this is not what I was looking for. Because my struggle is that for example at time 3 I buy 10145 stocks of MSFT and at time 5 I sell those stocks. And the sale of those stocks has to impact my cash levels at time 5 which in turn will impact the MSFT stocks I buy at time 7. And what you did only uses the level of cash [i-1] to determine the number of stocks bought [i] but I also need the price and number of stocks sold [i] to impact the level of cash [i]